# Read JSON and into HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, request

In the following code, I try to show stings of the source in a HTML table. The problem at this is, that instead of the string I see "undefined". Thanks in advance!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Table:</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
obj = { table: "customers", limit: 20 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        txt += "<table border='1'>"
        for (x in myObj) {
            txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>";
        }
        txt += "</table>"        
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://www.bayern-fahrplan.de/DDIP01?CoordSystem=WGS84&MinX=11%2C012742519378662&MinY=49%2C465725517007506&MaxX=11%2C035208702087402&MaxY=49%2C47637864525285&ts=154159795103", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Presumably this is because what was returned from the server was not in the format you're assuming when trying to read it in your code. But you haven't shown us a sample of that data, so we can't tell you exactly how to fix it. All we can say is "inspect the structure being returned and amend your code accordingly to read from it correctly". If you're still stuck, edit the question to show us a sample of the response from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and I have looked at the JSON that is being returned in the response. An example of an object being returned is as follows:

```
    {"CurrentStop":"KURGAR:1",
    "DayOfOperation":"07.11.2018",
    "Delay":227,
    "DirectionText":"Stadtgrenze",
    "ID":"35094510",
    "JourneyIdentifier":"2009441",
    "Latitude":"49,466061",
    "LatitudeBefore":"49,467044",
    "LineText":"38",
    "Longitude":"11,012931",
    "LongitudeBefore":"11,013168",
    "MOTCode":5,
    "ModCode":5,
    "NextStop":"STAD:6",
    "Operator":"VAG",
    "ProductIdentifier":"BUS",
    "RealtimeAvailable":1,
    "Timestamp":"2018-11-07T15:13:44+01:00",
    "TimestampPrevious":"2018-11-07T15:12:40+01:00",
    "VehicleIdentifier":"589",
    "X":"11,012931",
    "XPrevious":"11,013168",
    "Y":"49,466061",
    "YPrevious":"49,467044"}
```

In the for loop in your code you are attempting to get a `name` property of `myObj[x]` as follows:

```
for (x in myObj) {
    txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>";
}
```

However as you can see in the JSON above, there is no `name` property and this is why you are getting `undefined`.

If you replace `name` in the above "for loop" code with a correct property name then your code will work. For example the following:

```
for (x in myObj) {
    txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].CurrentStop + "</td></tr>";
}
```

I have tested this and it works. Hope this helps.

Comment: @PeterStadler No problem :) Feel free to mark it as the answer if it is the answer you were looking for. Glad to have helped :)